# Ubuntu frozen boot after moving root partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub, gparted, move-partition

[Go to the end to see the solution]
I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu and Windows 10.
I have enlarged and moved (to the left) Ubuntu's "/" partition with GParted.

When I boot my system, I correctly visualize the grub menu from which I can select either Ubuntu or Windows 10.
Windows is perfectly working, whereas when I try to boot Linux it gets stuck on a black screen.
I have tried to launch the kernel in recovery mode, but it freezes after having printed the following:

```
Loading Linux 5.4.0-65-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

I guess the partition data was not damaged.
Do you know a solution better than system reinstall?

---

**Update**
I have executed boot-repair from a live usb in order to generate the Bootinfo summary report (as suggested by @oldfred): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wn3XRs94Jq/

I have also tried the followin 3 strategies, without success.

### 1. Reinstall grub from `boot-repair` GUI

As explained here: https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/. It tells me it cannot find the packages `grub-efi` or `grub-efi-amd64-signed`.
**References**:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

### 2. From terminal:

Mount root and efi partition (yes, I have a separate efi partition) and import useful partitions from live usb Ubuntu

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt
for i in /sys /proc /run /dev /var /lib /usr /etc; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
```

Chroot in root partition

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Reinstall grub (efi).
Since I do it from the Ubuntu root partition (thanks to chroot), it correctly identifies Windows OS as well.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge grub-common
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64
sudo update-grub
grub-probe -t device /boot/grub
sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p1 # also tried with /dev/nvme0n1
sudo update-grub
```

But nothing changed.
**References**:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Purging_.26_Reinstalling_GRUB_2
- https://superuser.com/questions/903112/grub2-install-this-gpt-partition-label-contains-no-bios-boot-partition

### 3. From GParted live USB

- Perform "check" of the Ubuntu root partition /dev/nvme0n1p13 (passed)
- `sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p3 -y`
- `sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/nvme0n1p3`
- `sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/nvme0n1p3`

**References**:

- https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-a-bad-hard-drive-on-linux/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

---

**Update**.
After reinstalling the kernel from live usb in chroot, I get a kernel panic log when booting in recovery mode.
The last lines are:

```
0.4762681 eun: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE

0.477044] eun: security.SMACK64MMAP 0.477951) eun: security.apparnor

0.4787371 eun: security. ina

8.479513] eum: security.capability

0.4802771 eum: HMAC attrs: 0x1

0.4819921 PM: Magic number: 13:566:676 0.482765] vtconsole vtcon1: hash matches

0.4837521 rtc_chos 00:01: setting system clock to 2021-11-06T09:39:59 UTC (1636191599) 0.4848431 md: Maiting for all devices to be available before autodetect

0.485623] nd: If you don't use raid, use raid-noautodetect 0.486981) nd: Autodetecting RAID arrays.

0.4877591 nd: autorun ...

0.488526] md: ... autorun DONE.

0.4893201 UFS: Cannot open root device "UUID-b13c4a4c-9205-4547-83d8-641391500749" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6

8.4903641 Please append a correct "root=" boot option: here are the available partitions: 0.4911841 Kernel panic - not syncing: UFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-black(0,0)

8.4919711 CPU: 1 PID: 1 Conn: suapper/0 Not tainted 5.4.0-65-generic #73-Ubuntu 8.4927551 Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 5593/09PY2G, BIOS 1.17.0 07/27/2821

0.4935341 Call Trace:

8.494659] dump_stack Ox6d/0x9a

8.4957351 panic +0x101/0x2e3

8.496847] mount block_root+0x23f/0x2e8

0.4988051 mount_root 0x38/0x3a 0.4991241 prepare_nanespace 0x13f/0x194

8.580253] kernel_init_freeable 0x231/0x255

0.5013811 ? rest_init+0xb0/0xb0

8.5825991 kernel_init+0xe/0x110

0.503723] ret_from_fork 0x1f/0x10

8.5049351 Kernel Offset: 0x24000000 from Oxffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xfffffffffffffff) 8.586156] [ end Kernel panic - not syncing: UFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0.0) 1
```

NOTE: this text has been extracted by a picture with Google lens. So there may be some small typos. The original picture is
[image]

---

### Solution

Eventually I had to re-installed a brand new Ubuntu in my root partition without losing my data (which were in my /home partition, another partition on disk), using live USB. For each tried solution I kept getting errors that made me lose a huge amount of time, whereas the re-installation just took 15 minutes. **Strongly suggested!**  Probably the errors I got were due to the fact that the kernel in my root partition was 5.4.0-65, while the one on the us live key was 5.11.0.
**References:**

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179437/how-to-install-new-version-of-ubuntu-and-keep-home-partition-untouched

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair It may just need a fsck? https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: @oldfred I have updated my question. I hope it's more useful now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your chroot is the same as what Boot-Repair's default suggested fix is. The only thing I see which may be a Windows issue is nvme0n1p8 which is or should be Windows Reserved partition which must be unformatted. But it is showing as ext4. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition  Partition order is important, but I do not know if that is sectors on drive, where it is before the first NTFS or whether just the partition number which it now is p8?

Comment: Actually nvme0n1p8 is unformatted, even though` fdisk -l ` sees it as a Linux filesystem. I never formatted this partititon. On the same machine I also have Windows 10 which is booting correctly, so I assume that this partition is likely fine. Before the first ntfs I have nvme0n1p1, which is the EFI partition. I am not sure I have fully understood you comment.
Isn't there the possibility that during move and resize of the root partition (with GParted) something went wrong and some system files (like /etc/fstab) got corrupted?

Comment: Does it make sense trying to change the bootloader? For instance using systemd like here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=237610. Instead of grub2

Comment: If fdisk is seeing it as formatted, I would use gparted and change it to unformatted.  Was Boot-Repair report before or after you ran all the other commands? If before, run it again & post link. Otherwise I do not see what issue is. Do you get grub menu? Can you boot recovery mode?

Comment: Boot repair output has been generated after these commands have been run. GParted is already seing nvme0n1p8 as unformatted... I get grub menu as everything was fine and I can also boot windows 10 form there. When booting in recovery mode I just get ``` Loading Linux 5.4.0-65-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...```

Comment: Use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and choose total reinstall of grub and check install latest kernel. (will be like a chroot). What brand/model system? What video card/chip?

Comment: I have tried again with boot-repair but it keeps asking me for repositories, which is an unsolvable problem (I am correctly connected to the internet). I have seen many posts of other people with the same problem (https://askubuntu.com/questions/927420/boot-repair-is-asking-for-repositories) just to mention one. Now it asks me a repo where to fin [linux-generic] because I asked to reinstall the kernel. Before it used to ask me for [grub-efi-amd64-signed].. I don't know why but boot repair GUI is useless

Comment: I have reinstalled the kernel manually, from chroot and something seems to have been changed. Now, booting form recovery mode I get a lot of kernel panic. I am adding the log to the question's corpus.

Comment: Is or have updates been working. My kernel is 5.4.0-89-generic  in 20.04.3 and you are still showing -65 which was a while ago. And if Boot-Repair could not find repository, do you have an issue with repository? Review `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
`

Comment: Eventually I have re-installed a brand new Ubuntu in my root partition without losing my data (which were in my /home partition, another partition on disk). For each tried solution I kept getting errors that made me lose a huge amount of time, whereas the re-installation just took 15 minutes. Highly suggested!  
Probably the errors I got were due to the fact that the kernel in my root partition was 5.4.0-65, while the one on the us live key was 5.11.0.

Comment: While in forums & here we are willing to help fix issues for as long as it may take. And many of us believe in good backups and new clean install if issue lasts more than a few hours of trying to fix it. I keep /home inside / (root) and have large data partitions that are separately backed up.

Comment: Thank you for your help! At least it was instructive!